# how can I share variables between glsl and python in the bge?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, shaders, memory-management

I am currently writing a glsl shader in the bge,

My question is, if I have glsl embedded into my python script, how can I if possible share memory/variables between my glsl and my python so the below is both valid and functioning.

I would like it so that i in f is the same as the i in the for loop.

```
print("creating shads")
FragmentShaders = []

for i in range(257):
    f = """        
        varying vec4 maps[256];
        void main()
       {
          gl_FragColor = maps[i];//this is not valid because i doesn't exist here.
       }        
    """   

    FragmentShaders.append(f)

print("end of shads")
```

the rest of the code works perfectly, but I see no reason to put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to my surprise the bge keeps glsl functions as strings until they're in use, but for some reason you can't use replace on them. Therefore if you want to share memory between a glsl shader and the bge you can do something like this below. worked great for me anyway.

```
for i in range(257):
    f = """        
        varying vec4 maps[256];
        void main()
       {
          gl_FragColor = maps[100];//this is not valid because i doesn't exist here.
       }        
    """   
    f=list(f)
    a=str(i)

    f[100:103]=a

    f="".join(f)    
    print('verify:',f[100],f[101],f[102])

    FragmentShaders.append(f)
```